# How to solve threads conflict because of long time cost of SQL statements?

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, sql-server-2008

I'm going to insert some data from DataBase O into DataBase A,and then write logs into DataBase B.And now,I have a function like this:

```
list=DataBaseO.getdata();
if(list.id not in DataBaseB)
{
    insert data into DatabaseA;
    insert log into DatabaseB;
}
```

It just runs as I want.But when I put it into a multiple-thread program,it,however,goes wrong. The logs are to big,so it cost  a lot of time to insert it into DataBase B.When thread No.1 is trying to insert a log,thread No.2 is already tries to find whether list.id is in BataBase B.So,I finally get 2 same data in the DatabaseA.How could I solve this?

Ps,I'm using C#

Comment: Don't send the second command until the first one is finished and committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could lock the operations using a [Lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx). That way you can let threads wait on eachother. With your example code it would look like:

```
list=DataBaseO.getdata();
if(list.id not in DataBaseB)
{
lock(theLock) {
        insert data into DatabaseA;
}
lock (theLock) {
        insert log into DatabaseB;
}
}
```

You would have to declare 'theLock' somewhere before you start your threads and make it accessible. The lock object could be any type of Object, I personally tend to just use a basic Object for it.

Note that you could also lock both operations in the same lock if you want the whole process to be done (write data to database A and write logs to B). In either case multi threading won't give you much of a performance boost as the threads would constantly be waiting on each other to access the database.

Comment: lock() doesn't work here,the SQL statements has already been sent to the server,and the object has been released.But it takes time for server to deal with it.

Comment: Ah my bad, I figured you wanted to wait for the transaction to finish. How do you do the log insert then? If its a transaction the sql server can never give out data before its done rebuilding its indexes (aka process all data). Is it done by executing a remote job?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a flag which will indicate if logs into DatabaseB are finished inserting. So if another thread will attempt getting data, it would wait untill the flag is cleared. (Use a timer for your threads, which will periodically check for the flag).

Also it goes without saying that you should declare only one instance of your flag. So either set your flag in the DB, either declare it **static** in your code (depending if threads from more applications would check this flag or only one application will always be running).

So your code would look something like this:

```
list=DataBaseO.getdata();
if(list.id not in DataBaseB && logsInsertedFlag )
{
    logsInsertedFlag = false;
    insert data into DatabaseA;
    insert log into DatabaseB;
    logsInsertedFlag = true;
}
```

Anyway, as I personally see it, the only way to speed up your process is to speed up insterting your logs into DatabaseB.

Hope my answer helps.